# how to execute oozie shell action with script having curl command

Tags: oozie

Apologies, as i have not tried this earlier.

Hi,

I need to create oozie workflow that exeuctes a shell script. The shell script has curl command which downloads a specific file from client's repo.

As commands in shell scripts are only able to recognize hdfs directories, how could i execute the script.?

Lets say below is the Sample code:

```
curl -o ~/test.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar

hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ~/test.jar /user/sr/test2
```

How can i execute the script with above two commands using oozie.?

Comment: have you configure the Oozie Workflow.xml, if yes do share the same as well....you can look in Link[link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_ShellActionExtension.html) for reference. You have to upload the Script in DFS location as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer...

data=`curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.csv`
echo "$data" | hdfs dfs -appendToFile - /path/to/hdfs/directory/PPP.csv